# Azure Data Factory Cosmos DB sql api 'DateTimeFromParts' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Copy Activity in my Datafactory(V2) to query Cosmos DB (NO SQL/SQLAPI). I have a where clause to build datetime from parts using DateTimeFromParts datetime function. THis query works fine when I execute it on the Cosmos DB data explorer query window. But when i use the same query from my copy activity I get the following error:

"message":"'DateTimeFromParts' is not a recognized built-in function name."}]}
ActivityId: ac322e36-73b2-4d54-a840-6a55e456e15e, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.5.1 Host/64-bit

I am trying convert a string attribute which is like this '20221231', this translates to  Dec 31,2022, to a date to compare it with current date, i use the DateTimeFromParts to build the date, is there another way to convert  this '20221231' to a valid date

Select * from c where
DateTimeFromParts(StringToNumber(LEFT(c.userDate, 4)), StringToNumber(SUBSTRING(c.userDate,4, 2)), StringToNumber(RIGHT(c.userDate, 2))) < GetCurrentDateTime()

I suspect the error might be because the documentdb-dotnet-sdk might be an old version. Is there way to specify which sdk to use in the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to repro this and got the same error.
Instead of changing the format of `userDate` column using `DateTimeFromParts` function, try changing the **GetCurrentDateTime()** function to `userDate` column format.

**Workaround query:**

```sql
SELECT  *  FROM c
where c.userDate <  
replace(left(GetCurrentDateTime(),10),'-','')
```

**Input data**

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "userDate": "20221231"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "userDate": "20211231",
    }
]
```

**Output data**

```json
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "userDate": "20211231"
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on your suggestion the comparison is now based on comparing two strings, i am wondering if this work for all possible dates. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the slow reply here. Holidays slowed getting an answer for this.

There is a workaround that allows you to use the SDK v3 which would then allows you to access the DateTimeFromParts() system function which was released in .NET SDK v.3.13.0.

Option 1: Use AAD authentication (i.e Service Principal or System or User Managed Identity) for the Linked Service object in ADF to Cosmos DB. This will automatically pick up the .NET SDK v3.

Option 2: Modify the linked service template. First, click on Manage in ADF designer, next click on Linked Services, then select the connection and click the {} to open the JSON template, you can then modify and set `useV3` to true. Here is an example.

```
{
  "name": "<CosmosDbV3>",
  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
  "properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "CosmosDb",
    "typeProperties": {
      "useV3": true,
      "accountEndpoint": "<https://sample.documents.azure.com:443/>",
      "database": "<db>",
      "accountKey": {
        "type": "SecureString",
        "value": "<account key>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried option 2, and tried to preview the data, i got the same error

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Only thing I can think of is make sure the template saved and the copy job is using the one you modified.  I tried looping in people from ADF but they insist on a support ticket to further troubleshoot. Apologies I cannot be of more help.